# python performance problems using loops with big tables

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, chained-assignment

I am using python and multiple libaries like pandas and scipy to prepare data so I can start deeper analysis. For the preparation purpose I am for instance creating new columns with the difference of two dates. 
My code is providing the expected results but is really slow so I cannot use it for a table with like 80K rows. The run time would take ca. 80 minutes for the table just for this simple operation.

The problem is definitely related with my writing operation:

```
tableContent[6]['p_test_Duration'].iloc[x] = difference
```

#### Moreover python is providing a Warning:

[image]

## complete code example for date difference:

```
import time
from datetime import date, datetime

tableContent[6]['p_test_Duration'] = 0

#for x in range (0,len(tableContent[6]['p_test_Duration'])):
for x in range (0,1000):
    p_test_ZEIT_ANFANG = datetime.strptime(tableContent[6]['p_test_ZEIT_ANFANG'].iloc[x], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    p_test_ZEIT_ENDE = datetime.strptime(tableContent[6]['p_test_ZEIT_ENDE'].iloc[x], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    difference = p_test_ZEIT_ENDE - p_test_ZEIT_ANFANG

    tableContent[6]['p_test_Duration'].iloc[x] = difference
```

## the correct result table:

[image: ---]

Comment: if you use pandas, why don't you use pandas datetime ? If you can just add sample input it would be easier to help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take away the loop, and apply the functions to the whole series.

```
ZEIT_ANFANG = tableContent[6]['p_test_ZEIT_ANFANG'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
ZEIT_ENDE = tableContent[6]['p_test_ZEIT_ENDE'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
tableContent[6]['p_test_Duration'] = ZEIT_ENDE - ZEIT_ANFANG
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working perfect! Just one comment on your code: there are two brackets missing to close the .apply() method.

Comment: Glad it worked, added the missing brackets, I don't know how people manage with lisp brackets ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can vectorize the conversion of dates by using `pd.to_datetime` and avoid using `apply` unnecessarily.

```
tableContent[6]['p_test_Duration'] = (
    pd.to_datetime(tableContent[6]['p_test_ZEIT_ENDE']) -
    pd.to_datetime(tableContent[6]['p_test_ZEIT_ANFANG'])
)
```

---

Also, you were getting the `SettingWithCopy` warning because of the chained indexing assingnment

```
tableContent[6]['p_test_Duration'].iloc[x] = difference
```

Which you don't have to worry about if you go about it in the way I suggested.

Comment: This answer is better ~For efficiency purpose should not consider `apply` too.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are fine, but I would recommend that you avoid chained indexing in general. The pandas docs [explicitly discourage chained indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) as it either produces unreliable results or is slow (due to multiple calls to __getitem__). Assuming your data frame is multi-indexed, you might replace:

```
tableContent[6]['p_test_Duration'].iloc[x] = difference
```

with:

```
tableContent.loc[x, (6, 'p_test_Duration')] = difference
```

You can sometimes get around this issue, but why not learn the method least likely to cause problems in the future?