# python performance problems while classifing column values

Tags: python, pandas, data-science-experience

This question is strongly related to my question earlier: 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45057978/python-performance-problems-using-loops-with-big-tables)
Sorry that I have to ask again!

The code below is running and delivering the correct results but its again somehow slow (4 mins for 80K rows). I have problems to use the Series class from pandas for concrete values. Can someone recommend how I can instead classify those columns? 

Could not find relevant information in the documentary: 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html

## Running Code:

```
# p_test_SOLL_test_D10

for x in range (0,len(tableContent[6])):
    var = tableContent[6].loc[x, ('p_test_LAENGE')]
    if float(tableContent[6].loc[x, ('p_test_LAENGE')])>=100.0:
        tableContent[6].loc[x, ('p_test_LAENGE')]='yes'
    elif (float(tableContent[6].loc[x, ('p_test_LAENGE')]) <30.0 and float(tableContent[6].loc[x, ('p_test_LAENGE')]) >= 10):
        tableContent[6].loc[x, ('p_test_LAENGE')]='yes2'
    elif (float(tableContent[6].loc[x, ('p_test_LAENGE')]) <10.0 and float(tableContent[6].loc[x, ('p_test_LAENGE')]) >= 5):
        tableContent[6].loc[x, ('p_test_LAENGE')]='yes3'
    else:
        tableContent[6].loc[x, ('p_test_LAENGE')]='no'

print (tableContent[6]['p_test_LAENGE'])
```

## Series Try:

```
if tableContent[6]['p_test_LAENGE'].astype(float) >=100.0:
    tableContent[6]['p_test_LAENGE']='yes'
elif (tableContent[6]['p_test_LAENGE'].astype(float) <30.0 and tableContent[6]['p_test_LAENGE'].astype(float) >= 10):
    tableContent[6]['p_test_LAENGE']='yes1'
elif (tableContent[6]['p_test_LAENGE'].astype(float) <10.0 and tableContent[6]['p_test_LAENGE'].astype(float) >= 5):
    tableContent[6]['p_test_LAENGE']='yes2'
else:
    tableContent[6]['p_test_LAENGE']='no'


print (tableContent[6]['p_test_LAENGE'])
```

Comment: There are way more experienced people with Pandas (probably looking at this question right now). So, I won't even try to give you a canonical approach. However, the advice in your previous question mentions "vectorization" and "take away the loop". If you're using `for` loops, they run in roughly Python time (computationally) and you might as well not bother with `numpy` or `pandas` and just go vanilla python. It requires a shift in thinking, and a couple of tutorials might suit you well here before proceeding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have your `df` to test so you need to modify the following code.
Assume that min of `df` is greater than `10e-7` while max of `df` is less than `10e7`

```
bin = [10e-7,5,10,30,100,10e7]
label = ['no','yes2','yes1','no','yes']
df['p_test_LAENGE_class'] = pd.cut(df['p_test_LAENGE'], bins=bin, labels=label)
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you! The cut method was what I've been looking for!